# Is it possible to get request data from web server to console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, rest, console-application

I have this website that has web server which is Apache Tomcat and its connected MySQL and a console application (C#).

What I planned to do is, this console application  will request to web server to get a data from MySQL
and web server send data to console application.

Is it possible? How can implement this?

Should I use REST API  to get the data in web server?

Comment: You should be able to do what you want through the Console App through the `HttpClient` class. Not sure what sort of data your server exposes, but it is usually recommended that you provide data in a structure way, such as JSON or XML so that it can be easily parsed from clients.

Comment: Does getting data using REST API is different from getting the data through HTTP Client?

Comment: A REST Api is an API hosted on a server which provides information to its clients. The information is usually in JSON format and accessed using a mix of HTTP Verbs and URI's, for instance a GET request on the `/api/clients` will *get* you all the clients, while a `PUT` request on `/api/clients` will allow you to *create* clients. REST Api's offer a structured way of performing the usual CRUD operations.
C#'s `HttpClient` is a utility class which allows you to specify the request verb (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE,etc) and the URI you want to hit. The `HttpClient` is used client side (Your console app)